# Why does my iPhone ask for a screen time password when I’ve never set up one?

Tags: iphone, password, screen

I literally set up screen time on my iPhone this morning and went through all the app limits, “this is my iPhone” etc. However I have never set up a screen time password on that device before and when I tried to change the app limits “enter screen time password” popped up on my screen and I have no idea what the password is. I have other Apple devices (with the same Apple ID) with screen time set up I think, so could this be part of the problem? Thanks

Comment: Anyone with access to your phone /account / devices can mess with the settings. Are you asking how to disengage this or hoping someone was tracking your account and can tell you who toggled it on or confirmation that this could be enabled from another device?

Comment: I just want to confirm that it’s possible that the screen time password could have been shared from my other devices

Comment: OK - great - that’s not detailed in the FAQ - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210387 So getting some confirmation will be helpful